# Windows 7: How to create a process launcher where the launched process will occupy the same task bar icon?

Tags: c#, windows-7, taskbar

We're running p4v from within Perforce with a launcher, to make sure everybody is using the latest approved version of p4v and to make sure all the custom tools are always up-to-date. One issue, which for some people is big enough not to use the launcher, is that when the launcher has been pinned to the task bar, p4v will not use that space in the task bar, but its own.

I've been looking at System.AppUserModel.ID, but the documentation is not really helping. Does anyone have experience with the same problem and can point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

Sebastiaan

Comment: Give p4v and your launcher the same AppID. That will cause them to be treated as the same logical application.

Comment: Is it possible to give an existing application an AppID? As far as I can tell, p4v has not an explicit AppID, so it's generated. How can I give the launcher the same AppID as the generated ID?

Comment: Sorry, I thought p4v was a program you wrote. If p4v sets an explicit one, then that's the one to use. If it is using an autogenerated one, then I guess you're stuck. "[Applications cannot retrieve a system-assigned AppUserModelID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#which)".